# PHP fucntion doesn't run in wordpress. [Creating a Shortcode]

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have the following **PHP code which runs** and diplays the pricing table. I want the function to check if a user already has a membership, and display a pricing table if no membership is found - MembershipLevel('1'):

```
    <?php
if(MembershipLevel('1'))
{
    ?>
<div class="PRICING TABLE">
</div>

  <?php
}
else echo "Full Membership Obtained"
?>
```

Now I want to make this a function. I tried:

```
<?php function get_pricing(){
if(MembershipLevel('1'))
{
    ?>
<div class="PRICING TABLE">
</div>
<?php
;}
else echo "Full Membership Obtained";}
?>
<?php get_pricing();
add_shortcode( 'pricing', 'get_pricing' ); ?>
```

But when I try to put [pricing], the shortcode doesn't dipslay anything. Infact, the function get_pricing(); itself doesn't run.
EDIT: the function does run. Which is why it makes me wonder why the shortcode doesn't work. Other theme shortcodes work just fine.

Comment: Did you add the `;` to `<?php
;}
else echo "Full Membership Obtained";}`

Comment: @chop62 I got the function to work, it displays the content below the footer, which is why I want to associate it with a shortcode to display it on page

Comment: `<?php
;}
else echo "Full Membership Obtained";}` Change To `<?php
}
else echo "Full Membership Obtained";}`

Comment: @chop62 I did, nothing changed. when I call the function get_pricing(); it displays the table. However, I don't see why it doesn't assoiciate the shortcode with the function using add_shortcode('pricing', 'get_pricing' ); which is basically the last line of php code. The get_pricing(); works fine on its own

Comment: Is this code in functions.php?

Comment: @RST No. I created a new template for the page. Copied the default and added this custom php code at the bottom

Comment: I also tried to use <?php include '/wp-includes/shortcodes.php';?>

Comment: Looking at this https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode 

Think you need to do something like this 

`<?php 
$price = get_pricing();
function pricing_func( $price ) {
 return "pricing = {$price['pricing']}";
}
add_shortcode( 'pricing', 'pricing_func' ); ?>`

Comment: The trouble is that even the wordpress examples in the codex above don't work. I copy paste the exact 'working' code and it doesn't work.

Comment: Shortcodes CAN'T output content. You must return the content instead

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your functions.php

```
<?php 
  function get_pricing() {
    $text = '';

    if(MembershipLevel('1')) {
      $text = '<div class="PRICING TABLE"></div>';
    } else {
      $text = 'Full Membership Obtained';
    }

    return $text;
  }

  add_shortcode( 'pricing', 'get_pricing' ); 
?>
```

In a post you could use

```
[pricing]
```

In a template you could use

```
echo do_shortcode('pricing');
```